# Building Boost Libs

Tags: boost

About 3 months ago I managed to build boost libs and left myself the following instructions:

Extract boost to ->
  cd C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_43_0

Build bjam ->
  bootstrap.bat

Issue the following command ->
bjam --toolset=msvc-9.0 stage variant=debug  threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static --with-filesystem --with-iostreams --with-regex --with-serialization --with-signals --with-system --with-thread --with-wave

before it build the libs in the default 'stage' directory. Now the command fails to accept any of the lib names. If i remove filesystem, it fails on the next... and so on.

C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_44_0>win32_build_boost_libs.bat
error: wrong library name 'filesystem' in the --with- option.

Can anyone tell me why I've spent 3 hours trying to google for this but can't find anything :-(

I'm sure its something stupid but the process works on my old laptop but not on my new. They both have the same visual studio, version of boost, archive of boost, path variables... It really is quite frustrating.

Comment: You say "same visual studio, version of boost, archive of boost" but the prompts are boost_1_43_0 for working and boost_1_44_0 for errors

Comment: 10/10 for observation :-) In desperation I downloaded the latest boost_1_44_0 but it did the same. Ive worked out what it is, its copying the commands from Microsoft Word. There's some unicode chars or weird chars that are playing havoc with the parser. If I rewrite the command manually it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BlueGo to build boost - it supports different boost and Visual Studio versions: https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/bluego

[image]

Comment: bitbucket link is broken. I found another one here: https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BlueGo . But, It may disappear in future as was the last one. I'm yet to try the utility, but looks promising.